# OpenMP Working Precision

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

I am having an issue with the simple code bellow. I am trying to use OpenMP with GFortran. The Results of the code bellow for `x` should be the same with AND without `!$OMP` statements, since the parallel code and serial code should output the same result.

```
program test
implicit none
!INCLUDE 'omp_lib.h'
integer i,j
Real(8) :: x,t1,t2

x=0.0d0
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(i,j) shared(X)
Do i=1,3
   Write(*,*) I
   !pause
   Do j=1,10000000
   !$OMP ATOMIC
    X=X+2.d0*Cos(i*j*1.0d0)
   end do
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL Do

write(*,*) x    
end program test
```

But strangely I am getting the following results for `x`:

Parallel:`-3.17822355415XXXXX`

Serial:  `-3.1782235541569084`

where `XXXXX` is some random digits. Every time I run the serial code, I get the same result (-3.1782235541569084). How can i fix it? Is this problem due to some OpenMP working precision option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating-point arithmetic is not strictly *associative*. In f-p arithmetic neither `a+(b+c)==(a+b)+c` nor `a*(b*c)==(a*b)*c` is always true, as they both are in real arithmetic.  This is well-known, and extensively explained in answers to other questions here on SO and at other reputable places on the web.  I won't elaborate further on that point here.

As you have written your program the order of operations by which the final value of `X` is calculated is non-deterministic, that is it may (and probably does) vary from execution to execution.  The `atomic` directive only permits one thread at a time to update `X` but it doesn't impose any ordering constraints on the threads reaching the directive.

Given the nature of the calculation in your program I believe that the difference you see between serial and parallel executions may be entirely explained by this non-determinism.

Before you think about 'fixing' this you should first be certain that it is a problem.  What makes you think that the serial code's answer is the *one true answer* ?  If you were to run the loops backwards (still serially) and get a different answer (quite likely) which answer is the one you are looking for ?  In a lot of scientific computing, which is probably the core domain for OpenMP, the data available and the numerical methods used simply don't support assertions of the accuracy of program results beyond a handful of significant figures.

If you still think that this is a problem that needs to be fixed, the easiest approach is to simply take out the OpenMP directives.

Comment: I realized what you said. The code I showed in my question was just a sample of what I'm facing in my real code, which performers a lot more calculations. I am writing a code to benchmark a new methodology that I am developing for Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD). So that is why I am concerned about this, since I will need maximum precision digits as possible to compare and benchmark the methodologies.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what High Performance Mark said, another source of discrepancy is that the compiler might have emitted x87 FPU instructions to do the math. x87 uses 80-bit internal precision and an optimised serial code would only use register arithmetic before it actually writes the final value to the memory location of `X`. In the parallel case, since `X` is a shared variable, at each iteration the memory location is being updated. This means that the 80-bit x87 FPU register is flushed to a 64-bit memory location and then read back, and some bits of precision are thus lost on each iteration, which then adds up to the observed discrepancy.

This effect is not present if modern 64-bit CPU is being used together with a compiler that emits SIMD instructions, e.g. SSE2+ or AVX. Those only work with 64-bit internal precision and then using only register addressing does not result in better precision than if the memory value is being flushed and reloaded in each iteration. In this case the difference comes from the non-associativity as explained by High Performance Mark.

Those effects are pretty much expected and usually accounted for. They are well studied and understood, and if your CFD algorithm breaks down when run in parallel, then the algorithm is highly numerically unstable and I would in no way trust the results it gives, even in the serial case.

By the way, a better way to implement your loop would be to use reduction:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(j) REDUCTION(+:X)
Do i=1,3
   Write(*,*) I
   !pause
   Do j=1,10000000
      X=X+2.d0*Cos(i*j*1.0d0)
   end do
end do
```

This would allow the compiler to generate register-optimised code for each thread and then the loss of precision would only occur at the very end when the threads sum their local partial values in order to obtain the final value of `X`.

Comment: Thank you, Hristo Iliev. I will implement the algorithm with `reduction` clause. My algorithm is not breaking down and it is very stable. The only thing I noticed was the issue that I pointed out in my question. I think it is due to the F-P arithmetic non-associativity as High Performance Mark said. I tried to use `Real(16)` instead of `Real(8)` and the results I got ware the same for serial and parallel implementation.

Comment: Actually, I can't use `Reduction` because in my real code the variable is a very large array. I read in "Parallel Programming in Fortran 95 using OpenMP" that "The variable `x`, aﬀected by the `Reduction` clause, must be of scalar nature and of intrinsic type. Even though, `x` may be the scalar entry in an array which is not of
deferred shape or assumed size. If this is the case, the computational overhead due to the creation and initialization of the private copies of the variables can be very large if `x` is a
large array".

Comment: I'd test the validity of that statement you quote from *Parallel Programming in Fortran 95 Using OpenMP*, it smacks of the sort of 'truth' which depends on compiler (version), platform, implementation details, all sorts of things.

Comment: @user2562505, the quote is simply untrue. The OpenMP standard states: "The type of a list item that appears in a reduction clause must be valid for the reduction operator or intrinsic." In Fortran 90 and later the `+` operator works on arrays too, therefore allowing for reduction over arrays. Still it is true that private copies are created and it could be very inefficient to reduce them in certain conditions, e.g. if only a handful of elements are actually modified by each thread.

Comment: In my specific case I am doing a summation, like the example above. But `x` is a large array of the form: `x(0:Imax,0:Jmax)` where `Imax` and `Jmax` are the mesh number of divisions in `x` and `y` directions respectively. I would like to discuss more about this topic with you guys. I have some different approaches on how to implement the parallelization of my code and I would like to know which one provides the best performance. Where can we discuss more about this topic?

Comment: Reduction usually improves accuracy, but the results remain non-deterministic, as well as dependent on number of threads.  Certain commercial applications are built with an option to skip parallelization of reduction operations, as it may be important to isolate non-deterministic results even at the cost of accuracy and speed.  It's usually better, when possible, (at least for performance) to use simd reduction in the inner loop and parallel reduction in outer loops, even if this requires separate inner and outer sum variables.

Answer (score -2):

I USED THE CLAUSE ORDERED WITH YOU CODE AND THIS WORK. BUT WORK WITH THIS CLAUSE IS THE SAME THAT RUN THE CODE IN SERIAL.

Comment: Using also non-captial letters would be nice and improves the readability of your answer.